# How to adjust bootstrap-vue img aspect?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue

I use [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/image):

```
<b-container fluid class="bg-light">
        <b-row>
          <b-col
            v-for="(item, index) in $store.getters.get_best_collect_list"
          >
            <b-img blank-color="#eee"
                   thumbnail
                   center
                   fluid :src="item.image_path"
                   :alt="item.name"
                   :key="item.id">
            </b-img>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
      </b-container>
```

But the display height is unconformity.

How can I adjust the height equal? 
[image: th]

===

I want to fill the height, stretch it with 1:1, and top, center.

Comment: How do you want them to fill the height? Stretch the image?

Comment: I want to fill the height, not stretch

Comment: Fill it with what? If you want the images to have equal height, but not stretch, the images will overflow horizontally. Is that what you want?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at CSS property `object-fit` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: @Hiws I misunderstand you, I want to stretch the image with 1:1 and top, center.